# Converting Cartesian circle to polar form

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am trying to convert circle equation from Cartesian to polar coordinates. I know the solution is all over the Internet but what I am looking for is the exact procedure and explanation, not just the solution. If we start off with:

$(x-a)^{2} + (y-b)^{2} = r^{2}$

and use

$x=r\cos{\theta}$

$y=r\sin{\theta}$

I got something that doesn't make a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: $x = r.cos \theta,\,\,\,\,\, 
y = r.sin \theta\,\,\,$ are to be put when the circle is centered at origin. Try putting $x= a+ r.cos\theta$ and so forth.

Comment: one of your problems is notational: $x\neq r\cos x$. rather, $x=r\cos\theta$.

Comment: 1. You're using "$r$" to denote both the radius of your circle (a real number) and a polar coordinate (the function on the plane that measures distance to the origin). 2. If the origin does not lie on or inside your circle, then your circle is not a polar graph. Are you perhaps looking for a _parametric_ description, as ellya gives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parametrization would be $x=r\cos\theta+a$, $y=r\sin\theta+b$. Since then $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^2\theta=r^2$

We take $x=r\cos\theta+a$, $y=r\sin\theta+b$, instead of $x=r\sin\theta+a$, $y=r\cos\theta+b$, as it produces a circle that is oriented anticlockwise.

Answer (score 1):

The true polar form of a de-centered circle is indeed given by

$$(\rho\cos\theta-a)^2+(\rho\sin\theta-b)^2=\rho^2-2\rho(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta)+a^2+b^2=r^2.$$

You get an explicit expression by solving the quadratic equation in $\rho$, giving

$$\color{green}{\rho=(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta)\pm\sqrt{(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta)^2+r^2-a^2-b^2}}$$ (only the positive roots should be considered).

Note that the term $(a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta)^2$ oscillates between $0$ and $a^2+b^2$ so that when $r<\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, the domain of $\theta$ is limited.

Of course, when $a=b=0$, this reduces to $\rho=r$.

---

With the trigonometric transform $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=d\cos(\theta-\phi)$, where $d^2=a^2+b^2$,

$$\rho=d\cos(\theta-\phi)\pm\sqrt{r^2-d^2\sin^2(\theta-\phi)}.$$

Comment: "only the positive root should be considered" — are you sure? If the circle doesn't encircle the origin, in polar coordinates you *need* two values of $\rho$ for each valid $\theta$ except for the two extremal values. What is true is that only positive (actually, *non-negative*) values for $\rho$ should be considered. This translates into only considering the positive root *iff* the root is larger than the absolute value of the first term (anyway, +1 for the otherwise correct answer).

Comment: OK, took me some time, but now I understand: With "root" you are *not* referring to the square root, but to the roots of the quadratic equation. You might consider formulating this differently, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Well, if you don't care about people misunderstanding your post (and there *is* at least one person who misunderstood you, namely me), well, then just ignore my comment. But no amount of pedantry will change the fact that people *can* misunderstand your post (and the proof of that is in the fact that I did).